# creating menu using bootstrap not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried to create a responsive menu using bootstrap. But I have no idea how to implement this.

My idea is, on left side one logo should be there and on right side menu should be there.

Below is my menu idea. Have a look,

[image: Menu]

Is it possible to make a menu like above image using bootstrap.

I have tried the below code,

```
<div class="menu">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 vcenter">
                    <p><img src="<?php echo base_url("assets/images/logo.png"); ?>" alt="Logo" /></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9 vcenter">
                    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
                        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
                        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Look here : http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default

Comment: You really need to make an attempt first using the doc examples, and then ask again if you encounter a specific problem.

Comment: @ZimSystem : check the question again. I have edited.

Comment: What is not working ? http://www.bootply.com/Ltm7bd7CZN Javascript error ? Css problem ? Something else ? I think you should restart from scratch with the doc example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this way you can achieve it---

**Go full screen**

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Secure Login</title>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      
        
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Insights</a></li> 
      
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: May I know the reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Allright I don't know if you posted the full code, but you should begin from the begin, including bootstrap CSS and boostrap JS (and jquery).

Congrat's, Bootstrap it's really cool and for old developers like me, it's heaven.